# Bar Between two points in a container

Tags: html, css

I have a container (`CardContainer`) that has a few child elements (snippet below) and I would like to build a bar that I can fill in between the two points (the card image and the chevron) and I am finding it difficult to figure out the right way to do this. How can I make sure that it stays between these two elements even when the page is different sizes?

```html
<div class="CardContainer">
  <div class="CardLineItem">
    <div class="CardLineItemImage"><img
        src="https://icm.aexp-static.com/Internet/Acquisition/US_en/AppContent/OneSite/category/cardarts/platinum-card.png">
    </div><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 320 512"
      class="CardLineItemChevron" height="25%" width="25%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        d="M285.476 272.971L91.132 467.314c-9.373 9.373-24.569 9.373-33.941 0l-22.667-22.667c-9.357-9.357-9.375-24.522-.04-33.901L188.505 256 34.484 101.255c-9.335-9.379-9.317-24.544.04-33.901l22.667-22.667c9.373-9.373 24.569-9.373 33.941 0L285.475 239.03c9.373 9.372 9.373 24.568.001 33.941z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    <div class="CardLineItemProgressBar">
      <div class="CardLineItemProgressBarOutline">test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried many different things from `position: relative`, `absolute`, etc and am struggling to figure this out.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a border bottom to the first div:

```
border-bottom: 5px solid black;
```

Another way can be to use `<hr>` tag between both of them:

```
<div class="CardContainer">
  <div class="CardLineItem">
    <div class="CardLineItemImage"><img
        src="https://icm.aexp-static.com/Internet/Acquisition/US_en/AppContent/OneSite/category/cardarts/platinum-card.png">
    </div><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 320 512"
      class="CardLineItemChevron" height="25%" width="25%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        d="M285.476 272.971L91.132 467.314c-9.373 9.373-24.569 9.373-33.941 0l-22.667-22.667c-9.357-9.357-9.375-24.522-.04-33.901L188.505 256 34.484 101.255c-9.335-9.379-9.317-24.544.04-33.901l22.667-22.667c9.373-9.373 24.569-9.373 33.941 0L285.475 239.03c9.373 9.372 9.373 24.568.001 33.941z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    <hr>
    <div class="CardLineItemProgressBar">
      <div class="CardLineItemProgressBarOutline">test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe you will need to put some extra css to the line, to make it look like you prefer.